# Get Value for element - if fail get InnerHTML

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm creating a chrome extension that can pull data from a webpage to speed up data entry. I'm trying to make this as easy for the users as possible, which is causing me some headache myself. I'm allowing them to put an id or a name for a field to lookup, and on my end, I have to determine if it's an input, or just text they're wanting pulled and see if the element exists with the id, and if not, check for an element with their provided value as a name. This has to be done with multiple fields that they provide.

I've tried a few iterations of code to do this. Currently I'm stuck on trying to get this code below to do the trick, but obviously it isn't working. Is there a better way to accomplish this via javascript only?

```js
var msg = {
  "first": "first_name_id_name",
  "last": "last_name_id_name",
  "email": "email_id_name",
  "phone": "phone_id_name"
}
var fields_to_find = JSON.parse(msg);
var data_to_push = {};
var current;
var ele;
for (var key in fields_to_find) {
  if (fields_to_find.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(fields_to_find[key]);
    ele = document.getElementById(fields_to_find[key]);
    if (!ele.value) {
      ele = document.getElementById(fields_to_find[key]);
      if (ele.innerHTML.length == 0) {
        ele = document.getElementsByName(fields_to_find[key]);
        if (!ele.value) {
          ele = document.getElementsByName(fields_to_find[key]);
          if (ele.innerHTML.length == 0) {
            current = "";
          } else {
            current = ele.innerHTML;
          }
        } else {
          current = ele.value;
        }
      } else {
        current = ele.innerHTML;
      }
    } else {
      current = ele.value;
    }
    data_to_push[key] = current;
  }
}
console.log(data_to_push);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first_name_id_name" value="John">
<p name="last_name_id_name">Doe</p>
<input type="text" name="email_id_name" value="johndoe@example.com">
<p id="phone_id_name">123-555-1234</p>
```

Any help you can provide would be awesome and much appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why the duplicate nested `if`s and `ele` definitions? If `!ele.value` on line 15, it still won't exist on line 19. Aside from that, you're really just saying `current = ele.value || ele.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strip off a lot of the superfluous nested if statements with a couple backup values like below. Also, because JSON is a native object in JS, you don't have to do a `JSON.parse` on your `msg` object.

```js
var msg = {
  first: "first_name_id_name",
  last: "last_name_id_name",
  email: "email_id_name",
  phone: "phone_id_name"
};
var data_to_push = {};
var current;
var ele;
for (var key in msg) {
  if (msg.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(msg[key]);
    ele = document.getElementById(msg[key]) || document.getElementsByName(msg[key])[0];
    if (ele) {
      current = ele.value || ele.innerHTML || '';
    } else {
      current = '';
    }
    data_to_push[key] = current;
  }
}
console.log(data_to_push);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first_name_id_name" value="John">
<p name="last_name_id_name">Doe</p>
<input type="text" name="email_id_name" value="johndoe@example.com">
<p id="phone_id_name">123-555-1234</p>
```

Comment: This solved my question and provided a more efficient way to accomplish my goal, which condensed my code tremendously. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

1 : Use `'` for `msg` variable.

2 : You do not need a lot of conditions.

There are a lot of Incorrect codes, to see all the changes check full code :

```js
var msg = '{ "first": "first_name_id_name","last": "last_name_id_name","email": "email_id_name",  "phone": "phone_id_name"}' ;

var fields_to_find = JSON.parse( msg ), 
    data_to_push = {}, 
    current , 
    ele ;

for ( var key in fields_to_find ) {

  if ( fields_to_find.hasOwnProperty ( key ) ) {

    console.log( fields_to_find[key] );

    ele = document.getElementById( fields_to_find[key] ) ? document.getElementById( fields_to_find[key] ) : document.getElementsByName( fields_to_find[key] )[0];
    
    if ( ele ) { data_to_push[key] = ( ele.innerHTML ) ? ele.innerHTML : ( ele.value ? ele.value : '' ) ; }

  }

}

console.log(data_to_push);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first_name_id_name" value="John">

<p name="last_name_id_name">Doe</p>

<input type="text" name="email_id_name" value="johndoe@example.com">

<p id="phone_id_name">123-555-1234</p>
```